# Expectation of exponential random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value, probability-limit-theorems

Can someone help me understand the parts I have highlighted in the proof? I have not understood how $|2c...|$ is upper bounded by $1$ and how one computes the expectation of an exponential random variable? This claim is available on **page 29** of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.00833.pdf
I believe the "background material" is all available on the same page just slightly above the claims.

[image]

Comment: Please do not [cross-post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/390288/expectation-of-ex-where-x-is-uniformly-distributed).

Comment: Ok. I was under the impression that math stackexchange and cross validated were different forums. One for mathematicians and the other for statisticians.

Comment: Cross-posting across SE sites is against site rules in general.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Ok, thanks for letting me know. Was not aware of this.